# Changing fragment views vs changing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Android newbie here. I'm trying to implement a sequencing where the user moves from popup to popup based on his actions in the previous popup(they're complex popups with several ui elements). I'm trying to figure out the benefits of using one fragment and simply switching the view that the fragment inflates vs. using a separate fragment for each popup. Any suggestions either way?

Comment: How many popups do you have in mind to use?

Comment: @Luksprog at least 3, up to 8

Comment: Assuming that those "pages" aren't simply static data(so they take input for user, they do actions on user action etc) I would use individual fragments. Having individual fragments makes it easier to wire those fragments differently(it would be easier to implement the back action with individual fragment than with switching views) . Simply switching views in  a fragment means you'll have to handle on your own the restore part of the fragment. Also, I wouldn't combine 7-8 complex layouts(along with setting listeners, data on those views) in one giant fragment class.